# Were all the remaining Immortals known to each other?

Tags: highlander-franchise, highlander

By the time of the Gathering, were all the remaining Immortals known to each other by sight? McLeod recognises Fasil in the MSG car park and knows Kastagir and the Kurgan, but had they *all* met previously through the centuries?

Comment: If they had all met at one point or another wouldn't there be only one?

Comment: @L.T.Smash - Many of the immortals are good friends, having spent centuries hanging around with each other.

Comment: @Valorum I knew it was straining really hard for that joke when I typed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can obviously confirm that MacLeod and the Kurgan had met prior to the Gathering, and the dialogue exchanged between MacLeod and Kastagir clearly indicates that they'd met before as well, likely on multiple occasions.

We can't be sure whether MacLeod and Fasil had met in person, but at the very least they'd clearly heard of one another, and may well have seen each other too. Either that, or they had a good idea of how many Immortals were left (i.e. very few), and could therefore guess who the other was through a process of elimination. It may also have been the case that Fasil had specifically tracked MacLeod down, like the Kurgan did in the Scottish Highlands, in which case he'd have known who to expect when he finally caught up to him, even if he'd never actually laid eyes on him before.

That said, we were given no indication of any prior meetings between Kastagir and the Kurgan, or Fasil and the Kurgan, and it doesn't seem terribly likely that Kastagir and Fasil would've survived, had they encountered the Kurgan previously (unless they were conveniently saved by outside inteference, like MacLeod was in 1536). That part is pure speculation, of course, but since we've nothing more than speculation to go on in that regard, **my best guess would be that they likely hadn't all met before**.

Comment: IIRC, they can sense when they came near another immortal. So they would not have to know someone to go looking for them, They would feel when they came near them. And then, depending upon their temperament, decide to either attack them or befriend them. It would appear that most befriended the other in the early times. possibly because they wanted allies in case they bumped into ones like Kurgan who clearly wanted to just kill everyone he came near.

Comment: I would also suspect that the one who had befriend others would also pass on to them others that they had met and befriended. So while W might have never met Z, he had met X who told him he knew Y who says Z is trustworthy. So I think they probably had not met all the others, but had heard of them.

Comment: @NJohnny - The Kurgan seems to enjoy psyching out his opponents. He meets McLeod on holy ground and ***doesn't wait around for him to come out***, so there's a goodly chance he'd have met other immortals and not immediately murdered them

Comment: @NJohnny - Yes, Immortals could sense the presence of one another within a certain range, but in some cases, they probably began hunting specific Immortals when they were too far apart for that sense to kick in. The Kurgan, for example, appeared to know of MacLeod's existence (and his immortality) well before he got near him.

Comment: @Valorum - We only saw the Kurgan taking his time while stalking MacLeod though; he wasn't shown to do that with Ramirez or Kastagir. Also, he tried to claim MacLeod's head immediately when they first met in the Scottish Highlands, and again when they fought outside the bar in New York. He only retreated when an NYPD helicopter showed up, and I suspect the presence of active law enforcement within NYC had a bearing on why the Kurgan refrained from initiating duels in broad daylight, or in front of multiple witnesses.

Comment: @LogicDictates - Oh sure. That doesn't preclude him from having met (and not killed) other immortals though. He's not especially sociable when we meet him, but that's after x hundred years of being around.

Comment: @Valorum - The Kurgan may have encountered other Immortals without killing them. But he was said to be the strongest of all Immortals, which implies that he'd taken more heads than any other, which in turn implies that he wasn't normally one to postpone confrontations. So if other Immortals did survive prior encounters with him, it was more likely by accident rather than design on his part. I suspect his relatively patient approach with MacLeod in 1980s New York was tailored to that specific opponent and landscape, rather than a reflection of his usual modus operandi throughout history.